# Second dropdown changes after selecting first dropdown in Joomla XML

Tags: plugin, joomla-3.7

I am creating these dropdown lists in XML for plugin:

- category multi-select dropdown,
- subcategory multi-select dropdown

(All data comes from database table)

I want when I select the first category dropdown, then the second dropdown list should come under the selected category on first dropdown. Example:-

```
<field name="category- list"
       type="sql"
       default=""
       label="Category"
       sql_select="e.*"
       sql_from="#__category AS e"
       sql_group="category"
       sql_order="e.cat_id ASC"
       key_field="cat_id"
       value_field="category"
       multiple="true"/>

<field name="subcategory - list depend on category list"
       default=""
       type="sql"
       label="SubCategory"
       sql_select="e.*"
       sql_from="#__subcategory AS e"
       sql_group="subcategory"
       sql_order="e.subcat_id ASC"
       sql_filter="cat_id"
       key_field="subcat_id"
       value_field="subcategory"
       multiple="true" />
```

Please help me out how to achieve this.

Given below is table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE category (
    cat_id int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    category varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
    PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)
) 

CREATE TABLE subcategory (
    subcat_id int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cat_id int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    subcategory varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    UNIQUE KEY subcat_id (subcat_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sql_filter` value must match the name of the field it is referring to. Since you have `cat_id` in your subcategory table which is referring to id in `category`, name your parent field as `cat_id`.

Your category field with name cat_id.

```
<field name="cat_id"
   type="sql"
   default=""
   label="Category"
   sql_select="e.*"
   sql_from="#__category AS e"
   sql_group="category"
   sql_order="e.cat_id ASC"
   key_field="cat_id"
   value_field="category"/>
```

Sub category field can be same as what you have now.

```
<field name="subcategory"
   default=""
   type="sql"
   label="SubCategory"
   sql_select="e.*"
   sql_from="#__subcategory AS e"
   sql_group="subcategory"
   sql_order="e.subcat_id ASC"
   sql_filter="cat_id"
   key_field="subcat_id"
   value_field="subcategory"/>
```

Comment: I did the same as suggested by you but didn't get the desired result what i want.

Comment: "Nagarjun" I need your input.How to achieve this?whatever you suggest but it doesn't  work. I need your email Id.

Comment: Please see documentation - https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type
Also try to remove `multiple="true"` parameter.

Comment: Add some `var_dump` debug points in libraries\joomla\form\fields\sql.php and see what is the output of your setup.